# How to activate CSS panel within HTML panel in a console of Firebag of Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, console

Please see two pictures.

1) Chrome OK. I have CSS panel in HTML panel.

[image]

**2) Firebag ISSUE**. There is no CSS panel in HTML panel. How to make in appear?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked the same question on Superuser and have got a detailed complete answer. Please visit a page:

https://superuser.com/questions/797422/how-to-activate-css-panel-within-html-panel-in-a-console-of-firebug-of-firefox

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the little arrow just below the Firebug close button is a toggle for the side panel?

You can always use the built in devtools instead of Firebug.